# app inventor 2 clear a list before fil it

Tags: android, list, mobile

I'm starting to use [app inventor 2](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu) and  I have an app that when click on a button it splits a string by a charactaer and add each element to a list.
[image]
But, actually, every time I click on the button it adds more elements at the end of the list.
[image]
[image]

I want to clear the list before fill it, How can I do it?

Comment: `List.clear()`?

Comment: There's no such block called List.clear

Comment: `clear()` is a method you can call on an instance of a List: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true

Comment: It depends on how you have implemented your list of strings, are you using just an array, or builtin ArrayList class or what?

Comment: Do you mean at first time you click on the button you see extra items on your list or on your second time? if it happens in first click, maybe you have used onPress listener instead of onClick listener, may you provide your onClick method?

Comment: In app inventor I use no code, just blocks like the image shown above. At first, the list is empty and there is no problem, the problem starts after the second click on the button, that's why I need to clear the list.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution asking for help in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest

I had to set the **label1** text to "", before load the **List**
[image]

thanks for your comments

Comment: Yes, it like reset function. Need to reset all data that being saved temporarily in `Label1` first before you add new data.